# How to get the type of Generic parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

How can I get the type of generic parameter?

For example:

```
void Example<T>()
{
  // Here I want to get the type of T (and how can I get if T is a primitive 
  // kind (int,bool,string) not class)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Type type = typeof(T);
```

That will get you the type object for type T.

`type.IsPrimitive` will tell you if it's one of the primitive types, see list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx

Also, note that although `string` is a basic type, which is very integrated with the .NET system, it is not a primitive. `System.String` is a full-fledged class, not a primitive.

Answer (score 6):

use the following for getting the type of T:

```
Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);
```

[typeof (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can get the type of T from an instance of the type T:

```
instance.GetType();
```